# How to line up a chemical structure in the table (chemfig)?

Tags: tables, chemfig

I have a table which has three rows of chemical structures. The structures in the second row are not lined up with the first and third rows. I tried to use `\vspace` to bring the structure down but it didn't help. How to change the position of the structure in the table? Any help is greatly appreciated!

My sample code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,doublespacing,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{morehelp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{easytable}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\setatomsep{2em}
\setbondoffset{1pt}
\setdoublesep{4pt}
\setbondstyle{line width=0.8 pt}


\renewcommand{\printatom}[1]{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering \caption{Test} 
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{20pt}>     {\centering\arraybackslash}p{160pt}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{60pt}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{160pt}>  {\centering\arraybackslash}p{20pt}}
\hline\hline
\\[-5pt] %controls the spacing between line and text
\vfill Entry & \vfill RBF$_3$K  &\vfill Ar-Br &\vfill R-R & Yield (\%)\\
\\[-5pt]\hline
\\[-7pt]
 1 & \chemfig[][scale=0.6]{[:30]--[::-60]--[::-60]-[:30]-[:-30]~[:0]-[:0]BF_3K} & \chemfig[][scale=0.6]{[:30]NC-*6(-=-(-[,1.3]Br)=-=)} & \chemfig[][scale=0.6]{[:30]--[::-60]--[::-60]-[:30]-[:-30]~[:0]-[:0]*6(-=-(-CN)=-=-)}&75\\
 2 & \chemfig[][scale=0.6]{[:30]--[::-60]--[::-60]-[:30]-[:-30]~[:0]-[:0]BF_3K} & \chemfig[][scale=0.6]{[:30]Cl-*6(-=-(-[,1.3]Br)=-=)} & \chemfig[][scale=0.6]{[:30]--[::-60]--[::-60]-[:30]-[:-30]~[:0]-[:0]*6(-=-(-Cl)=-=-)}&65\\      
\hline\hline
&\\
\end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}
\\
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a quick comment: Use `ex` instead of `pt` when dealing with vertical spacing (and `em` instead of `pt` when dealing with horizontal spacing); `pt` isn't font dependant.

Comment: I guess you want `m{}` type columns instead of `p{}` type ones. (BTW: all the packages you load seem unrelated to the problem. It doesn't even seem to be a `chemfig` problem..., also: the table currently exceeds `\textwidth`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't normally advertize the [`tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package (see [this post for reasons why](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121841/5049)) but in this case it is very handy. It scales the table horizontally to textwidth per default if you use its `X` type columns. Those columns have an optional argument for specifying the ratio of one column to another: `X[1]X[2]` would mean that the second column has a width twice as much as the first. In the optional argument you can also specify what traditional column type you'd like to have. I used `X[<num>c,m]` to have all cells centered both vertically and horizontally.

Instead of scaling each of the molecules I redefined the atom-sep and the `\printatom` command inside the `table` environment. Since this is inside the environment the effect of the redefinitions will stay local.

In the code below I removed all unnecessary packages. Instead I introduced [`mhchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) (I could also have used [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula)) for inline chemical formulae, and [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for nicer table rules:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setatomsep{2em}
\setbondoffset{1pt}
\setdoublesep{4pt}
\setbondstyle{line width=0.8 pt}
\renewcommand{\printatom}[1]{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
  \centering
  % locally change the molecule layout
  \setatomsep{.8em}
  % the following is necessary because you have defined \printatom with
  % a fixed fontsize:
  \renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\scriptsize\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}
  \caption{Test} 
  \begin{tabu}{X[3c,m]X[8c,m]X[5,cm]X[9c,m]X[3c,m]}
    \toprule\rowfont\bfseries
      Entry & \ce{RBF3K}  & \ce{Ar-Br} & \ce{R-R} & Yield (\%) \\
    \midrule
      1 & \chemfig{[:30]--[::-60]--[::-60]-[:30]-[:-30]~[:0]-[:0]BF_3K}
      & \chemfig{[:30]NC-*6(-=-(-[,1.3]Br)=-=)}
      & \chemfig{[:30]--[::-60]--[::-60]-[:30]-[:-30]~[:0]-[:0]*6(-=-(-CN)=-=-)}
      & 75 \\
      2 & \chemfig{[:30]--[::-60]--[::-60]-[:30]-[:-30]~[:0]-[:0]BF_3K}
      & \chemfig{[:30]Cl-*6(-=-(-[,1.3]Br)=-=)}
      & \chemfig{[:30]--[::-60]--[::-60]-[:30]-[:-30]~[:0]-[:0]*6(-=-(-Cl)=-=-)}
      & 65 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]