# How to make table spanning textwidth

Tags: tables, lengths

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,pgf}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\ratio}{\the\textwidth/4}

\hrulefill \\

\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
  \toprule
  \makebox[\ratio][l]{xx}&\makebox[\ratio][l]{1} &\makebox[\ratio][l]{2}&\makebox[\ratio][l]{3}\\
  \makebox[\ratio][l]{xx}&\makebox[\ratio][l]{1} &\makebox[\ratio][l]{2}&\makebox[\ratio][l]{3}\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

with output

[image]

How can I determine `\ratio` such that the table fills (exactly) the textwidth of the page? As seen, currently the `\ratio` is too large such that the table becomes wider than the text width.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you have two options, second one uses `tabularx` and I've found it in "The LaTeX Companion, 2e" (page 251).

First one uses a `p{.25\textwidth}` format for every column and suppresses inter-column space width `@{}`. No need for `pgfmath`. Don't forget that if you leaves a blank line before `\begin{tabular}` it will start a new indented paragraph. You can suppress indentation with `\noindent` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}*{4}{p{.25\textwidth}@{}}}
  \toprule
  xx&1&2&3\\
  xx&1&2&3\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YYYY}
  \toprule
  xx&1&2&3\\
  xx&1&2&3\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to force tables to be as wide as the normal text width; I know it's easy to do it with a word processor, but it doesn't make for prettier tables. To the contrary, expanded tables are usually uglier and less readable because the items are spread too far apart from each other.

You can use `tabularx`, if you really want to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXXX@{}}
\toprule
xx & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
xx & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `tabu` package enhances the possibilities, but its current version is unmaintained and the author has announced that the next version will be largely incompatible with the current one. See [Is the tabu package obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121841/is-the-tabu-package-obsolete)

Comment: Yes I agree, but I plan to change the number of columns dynamically in a script based on some input from the user, so I think I would like to have the table fill the page for now. Anyway, thanks for the good answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) (e.g). It will set the table to a given width without needing to calc the ration by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for better rules in the table

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {XXXX}
   \toprule
   xx & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

`tabu` comes with the new column type `X` which sets it’s width automatically, it has an optional argument taking `l`, `r`, `c` to adjust the alignment inside the cell or a numer to set uneven widths of columns. For example two columns, the first on right, the second one left aligned and twice the width of the first one, will be `X[r]X[2]` (`l` and `1` will be set by default).