# How to redefine thebibliography to put the bib list to a tabular?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref

The `bibliography` environment results in a list.

However, I want to produce a `tabular` with two columns. The first column is the id, like `1`, `2`..., and the second column is the content of the bib.

Any one have a solution?

This result should look like:

```
----------------------
| 1 | this is bib one |
----------------------
| 2 | this is bib two |
----------------------
```

### UPDATE:

I try to code from scratch, and get a workable solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1}
\newenvironment{tablebibliography}%
{\center\tabularx{\textwidth}{|c|X|}\hline%
\setcounter{enumiv}{0}%
\let\p@enumiv\@empty%
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arbic\c@enumiv}}%
{%\\\hline
\endtabularx\endcenter}

\def\@@preparetbibitem{%
\addtocounter{enumiv}{1}%
\ifnum\the\value{enumiv}>1\\\hline\fi}

\def\tbibitem{\@ifnextchar[\@tlbibitem\@tbibitem}
\def\@tlbibitem[#1]#2{\@@preparetbibitem\@biblabel{#1} & \if@filesw%
{\let\protect\noexpand\immediate\write\@auxout%
{\string\bibcite{#2}{#1}}}\fi\ignorespaces}

\def\@tbibitem#1{\@@preparetbibitem\@biblabel{\the\value{enumiv}} & \if@filesw%
\immediate\write\@auxout%
{\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{enumiv}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is reference\cite{itemone}, this is another reference\cite{itemtwo}.
\begin{tablebibliography}
\tbibitem{itemone} first item
\tbibitem[label]{itemtwo} second item
\tbibitem{itemthree} 3rd item \\\hline
\end{tablebibliography}
\end{document}
```

However, there are two issues:

- the 1st cell of the 1st line is not center-aligned.
- I must add `\\\hline` at the end of the last item, because I can't put it before `\endtabularx`, or it will complain `\hline noalign`.

How to solve these problems?

### UPDATE:

I replace `tabularx` with `tabu`, and the problems metioned above are solved. But the `\cite` link is broken. I don't kown how the `\bibitem` defines the link destination, so, what is the `\label` counterpart for `\cite` as to `\ref`?

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\newenvironment{tablebibliography}%
{\center\longtabu to \textwidth{|X[-1,c]|X[1,p]|}\hline%
\setcounter{enumiv}{0}%
\let\p@enumiv\@empty%
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arbic\c@enumiv}}%
{\\\hline
\endlongtabu\endcenter}
```

### UPDATE:

I solved the link problem.

```
\def\@tbiblink#1{%
\Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{cite.#1}\relax\hyper@anchorend}}
```

So `\cite` or `\hyper@link` links to `\@tbiblink`.

Comment: What is wrong with the current format?

Comment: @ThorstenDonig, I have a .doc document, and I am trying to rewrite it in latex. The bib-list is a table by its original format, so I have no choice.

Comment: The fact that it is a table in that document doesn't necessarily mean that you need a table in a LaTeX document. But until now you didn't show how the bibliography looks.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig, I just want to fit bib list in a table, I have revised the question.

Comment: You example doesn't belong to biblatex. It seems you just want to use a manual bibliography. Is this correct?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, For the moment, I just need manual bib. It'll be better to be extend to biblatex.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, by the way, there is a quickest but awful solution for `bibtex`. You just need to replace some commands in `*.bbl` file after the `bibtex` compile pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution is presented. May be `ltxtable` is better than `tabu`, but it's not an issue for now.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\usetablebibliography{%
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{\begin{tablebibliography}}{\end{tablebibliography}}%
\renewcommand{\bibitem}{\tbibitem}%
}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\settablebibheader[2]{\providecommand\tbibheaderone{#1}\providecommand\tbibheadertwo{#2}}
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1}
\newenvironment{tablebibliography}%
{\center\longtabu to \textwidth{|X[-1,c]|X[1,p]|}\hline%
\setcounter{enumiv}{0}%
\let\p@enumiv\@empty%
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arbic\c@enumiv}%
\@ifundefined{tbibheaderone}{}{\tbibheaderone & \tbibheadertwo \\\hline}%
}%
{\\\hline
\endlongtabu\endcenter}

\def\@@preparetbibitem{%
\addtocounter{enumiv}{1}%
\ifnum\the\value{enumiv}>1\\\hline\fi}

\def\@tbiblink#1{%
\Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{cite.#1}\relax\hyper@anchorend}}

\def\tbibitem{\@ifnextchar[\@tlbibitem\@tbibitem}

\def\@tlbibitem[#1]#2{\@@preparetbibitem\@tbiblink{#2}\@biblabel{#1} & \if@filesw%
{\let\protect\noexpand\immediate\write\@auxout%
{\string\bibcite{#2}{#1}}}\fi\ignorespaces}

\def\@tbibitem#1{\@@preparetbibitem\@tbiblink{#1}\@biblabel{\the\value{enumiv}} & \if@filesw%
\immediate\write\@auxout%
{\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{enumiv}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatother


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{test1,
    author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach,
        Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
    title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    location  = {Reading, Mass.},
    year      = {1994},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

this is a citation\cite{test1}

\settablebibheader{header1}{header2}
\usetablebibliography
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The compile command is:

```
pdflatex test
bibtex   test
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

And the result looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: bib tabular]

With `tabular` I could do it directly, but with `tabularx` I needed the `environ` package to collect the body. However `hyperref` links via `\cite` do not work, this is another matter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcounter{tbib}

\makeatletter
\def\tbibitem{\ifnum\value{tbib}>0 \expandafter\\\fi
              \refstepcounter{tbib}%
              \@ifnextchar[\@ltbibitem\@tbibitem}

\def\@ltbibitem[#1]#2{\if@filesw {\let\protect\noexpand
                      \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#2}{#1}}}\fi 
                      #1&}

\def\@tbibitem#1{\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
                  {\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{tbib}}}\fi 
                 \arabic{tbib}&}
\makeatother

\NewEnviron{thetablebibliography}%
{\setcounter{tbib}{0}%
 \let\bibitem\tbibitem
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|}
 \hline \BODY\\\hline
 \end{tabularx}\end{center}}

\makeatother

%% but \cite does not create valid links with 
%% \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
This is reference~\cite{itemone}, this is another reference~\cite{itemtwo}.

\begin{thetablebibliography}
\bibitem{itemone} first item
\bibitem[label]{itemtwo} second item
\bibitem{itemthree} 3rd item
\end{thetablebibliography}

\end{document}
% version avec tabular qui marche sans environ 
% \def\tbibitem{\tbibnewline\refstepcounter{tbib}%
%               \@ifnextchar[\@ltbibitem\@tbibitem}
% \newenvironment{thetablebibliography}%
% {\setcounter{tbib}{0}%
%  \let\bibitem\tbibitem
%  \def\tbibnewline{\gdef\tbibnewline{\tabularnewline}}%
%  \begin{center}
%  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
%  \hline }
% {\\\hline\end{tabular}\end{center}}
```

Comment: `tabular` is weak, so I choose `tabu`, which combines `longtable` and `tabularx`.

Comment: @MartinWang: You can also try [`ltxtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable), since [`tabu`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) has it's own [problems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121841/5764)...

Comment: @Werner, the syntax of `\LTXtable` is a little wierd. In my case, I have to write file in code to make it clean.