# hdashline with tabularx together with custom row height is not working

Tags: tabularx, arydshln

I tried to set up a table with different custom row height and a dashed line.

I'm using **tabularx** for the table and **arydshln** for the dashed line.

When I import arydshline before tabularx it starts throwing errors and does not draw the dashed line correct, when I import tabularx before arydshline ruins the right and left table border.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}

%\usepackage{arydshln} % Throws some errors and does not draw a correct line when placed here

\usepackage{tabularx}

%\usepackage{arydshln} % Ruins the left and right table border when placed here

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|} \hline

            \multicolumn{4}{|>{\hsize=4\hsize}X|}{}\\[-2ex]
            \multicolumn{3}{|>{\hsize=3\hsize}X}{\textbf{\Large 1}}  &
            \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedleft}X|}{2} \\[1ex] % \hdashline % That is the dashed line i want to show

        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

The example is reduced to the minimum, sadly I need all those three things, **dashedline**, **tables** and **custom row height**.

Here are some pictures of the output:

Crapped dashed line:

[image: crapped dashed line]

Crapped table border:

[image]

Comment: Try the 'tabu' package, it handles lines much better than other packages. Read the documentation for 'booktabs' and get rid of the vertical lines.

Comment: I don't know if tabu is a good Idea, I found this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121841/is-the-tabu-package-obsolete
Also the document is very long and only consists of tables.
I mean if there is no other way I have to use tabu but in first place I'm looking for an "easy" solution.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use struts in order to space your rows rather than using a fixed-height break `\\[<len>]`. Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,arydshln}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|>{\hsize=3\hsize}X}{\rule{1pt}{50pt}\textbf{\Large 1}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedleft}X|}{\rule[-20pt]{1pt}{20pt}2} \\
  \hdashline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I've used `\rule{<width>}{<height>}` to place a strut on the baseline and `\rule[<depth>]{<width>}{<height>}` to place a strut at `<depth>` below the baseline. In the above example, you should use a `<width>` of `0pt`, but I've used `1pt` to emphasize the strut.

Comment: Thanks your solution works great in expanding the row height but in one case I need smaller row height.