# Is tabu deprecated?

Tags: tabu

I need to start a project where many tables will be needed. I was going to use `tabu`, since it seems a rather complete package for typesetting tables.

However, on this site (which I trust) I read that `tabu` is no longer maintained and should not be used.

Is there a definite answer on this? Being in the "planning" phase, should I discard `tabu` and consider something else?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `tabu` last state is from 2010, but this does not mean that it is deprecated. Could you link to some posts where this is stated this way?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121841/is-the-tabu-package-obsolete/121847#121847

Comment: Yes, I read it on the question linked by @StevenB.Segletes. I'd like to know if since two years passed, something changed and there is now a definite answer

Comment: I have seen the author on the french list. So he still exists. But I haven't seen any indication that he is working on an update or working on existing bugs. So imho you are simply on your own: you can use the package but if you find a bug you will probably not get help from the author. And you should backup the package so that in the (imho rather improbable) case that an incompatible update appears in the near feature your document doesn't break.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks. But could it be possible that the package breaks due to updates in other packages I'm using? Say that I use package X which after update Z becomes incompatible with tabu, is this a possible scenario that I should take into account?

Comment: Have a look at the booktabs package

Comment: @MaxNoe Booktabs has less than half the features of tabu.

Comment: I don't know how much tabu relies of some specific code from other tabular related packages like longtable, array, siunitx, tabularx, colortbl etc. But apart from siunitx all this packages are rather fixed so I don't think that much would happen in this area. But updates mean changes and changes can always "awake" bugs. This is not confined to tabu.

Comment: Indeed, using `siunitx` internals could be problematic: I am working on a new version with revised code, and I specifically do not guarantee any internals in the code (the new version will have defined code-level interfaces for others to use).