# how to let revtex4-1 honor tabu

Tags: tabu, revtex

the example:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {l}
abc\\
def
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

I use xelatex to compile and the output shows:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               \relax 
l.9 \end{tabu}

? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
               \relax 
l.9 \end{tabu}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\tabuthepreamble ...ll@font \ignorespaces \@sharp 
                                              \unskip \tabu@cellright    \t...
l.9 \end{tabu}
```

the problem is that revtex4-1 redefine array and tabular in line 856 in revtex4-1.cls. Because I need to use a lot advanced features in tabu, are there any methods to get back the original definition of array and tabular?
Of course, such method can not change the source code of revtex4-1 and tabu.

Comment: Compile the `tabu` table in an external document and then `\includegraphics` the resulting PDF.

Comment: Mandatory reading for every `tabu` user: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121841

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think you can use `tabu` in `revtex4-1`. No hope.