# Coloring longtabus (with rowcolors)

Tags: longtabu, rowcolor

Another desperate I-google-together-my-document person here:
In my thesis I want to create light grey tables with darker grey top lines, but I encounter 2 problems:

If I use `\rowcolor[RGB]{240,240,240}` I get the result, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong when defining colors in the preamble. But that's the minor issue.

The big problem: I use a `longtabu` environment and can't get `\rowcolors` to work with it.

What I want it to look like (works):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}           
\usepackage{longtable, tabu}  
\usepackage[longtable,tabu]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\definecolor{grey1}{rgb}{240,240,240}
\definecolor{grey2}{rgb}{250,250,250}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}[H]{XXl}
\caption[Chemicals and Reagents] {\textbf{Chemicals and Reagents}} \vspace{2mm}\\
   \rowcolor[RGB]{240,240,240}
   \textbf{Product} & \textbf{Manufacturer} & \textbf{Reference}\\
   \rowcolor[RGB]{250,250,250}
   Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
   \rowcolor[RGB]{250,250,250}
   Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
   \rowcolor[RGB]{250,250,250}
   Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

The more elegant way I expected to work but doesn't:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}           
\usepackage{longtable, tabu}  
\usepackage[longtable,tabu]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\definecolor{grey1}{rgb}{240,240,240}
\definecolor{grey2}{rgb}{250,250,250}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{grey2}{grey2}
\begin{longtabu}[H]{XXl}
\caption[Chemicals and Reagents] {\textbf{Chemicals and Reagents}} \vspace{2mm}\\
   \rowcolor{grey1}
   \textbf{Product} & \textbf{Manufacturer} & \textbf{Reference}\\
   Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
   Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
   Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Thank you already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX!

`tabu` needs the `\taburowcolors` command, not `\rowcolors`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{grey1}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{grey2}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\taburowcolors[2] 2 {grey2..grey2}
\begin{longtabu}[H]{XXl}
    \caption{Chemicals and Reagents}\\[2mm]
    \rowcolor{grey1}
    \textbf{Product} & \textbf{Manufacturer} & \textbf{Reference}\\
    Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
    Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
    Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

result:[image: result 2]

---

Deprecated Answer, without `tabu`

The problem with your second document is that the `\rowcolors` command requires the `table` option for the package `xcolor`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{longtable}  
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{grey1}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{grey2}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{grey2}{grey2}
\begin{longtable}{lll}
    \caption{Chemicals and Reagents}\\[2mm]
    \rowcolor{grey1}
    \textbf{Product} & \textbf{Manufacturer} & \textbf{Reference}\\
    Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
    Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
    Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I have changed some other things, like switching from `longtabu` to `longtable`. I've been wary of `tabu` since encountering [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121847/131649) a while back. Your mileage may vary though, and that's certainly not where the problem in your example was located. Just thought I'd mention it.

I have also changed the way I define the `grey1` and `grey2` colors just to show you that the possibility exists; you can of course change it back to the `RGB` model if you prefer (or change the tone of your greys).

Also, you can just pass `[2mm]` as an optional argument to the `\\` command; no need to insert a `\vspace` before `\\`.

Result:[image: result]

Comment: Thank you alpenwasser for the quick answer! I already tried around with other table/longtable environments but I want to use the X columns that's why I'm using longtabu and that's giving me a "undefined control sequence" error.
Is there a way to use longtabu? Otherwise I really might need to figure out the ltxtable package.

Comment: the `table` option from `xcolor` package loads the `colortbl` package, so there's no longer a need to load it separately. additionally, do you know if `longtable` is a valid option for `xcolor`?

Comment: @Troy Yeah, I was just browsing the `xcolor` docs to see if I'd missed anything, thanks for the catch! `longtable` is indeed not a valid option, correct, and the example still works without the separate loading of `colortbl`. Will update my code accordingly.

Comment: @Anne I can get this to work with `longtabu`, more or less. But there is a small issue: `\rowcolors{2}...` still seems to color the caption; it doesn't seem to respect the starting value for where it is supposed to start coloring rows. But I understand your desire for those nice `X` columns; I'll see what can be done.

Comment: Ha! It actually works if I just load the table packages seperately as  \usepackage{longtable, tabu} and \usepackage[table]{xcolor} ! But you are right with the caption.

Comment: @Anne: Yup, `rowcolors` just needs the `table` option to work. After perusing the `tabu` documentation, I managed to fix the caption issue; it needs the `\taburowcolors` command. see edited example. Is that your desired result?

Answer (score 2):

With tabu you should use \taburowcolors for alternating colors. And if you want to define the color with values "240" etc, then you must use RGB as model, not rgb.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu}


\definecolor{grey1}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\definecolor{grey2}{RGB}{250,250,250}

\begin{document}

\taburowcolors[1]{grey1..grey2}
\begin{longtabu}[H]{XXl}
\caption[Chemicals and Reagents] {\textbf{Chemicals and Reagents}} \vspace{2mm}\\
   \rowcolor{red}%to show it better
   \textbf{Product} & \textbf{Manufacturer} & \textbf{Reference}\\
   Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
   Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
   Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```