# How to make \ifdefempty on datatool entries work in \longtabu?

Tags: etoolbox, tabu, datatool, longtabu

I have a .csv-file, which I want to make into a table using the `datatool`-package. The .csv-file ist structured like

*foo&bar&foobar*

where several lines are grouped together and only the first in each group contains entries for *foo* and *bar*, the rest only for *foobar*. The entries may contain math.

I tried to check for the first line in a group with `\ifdefempty` from `etoolbox`-package and printing out `\hline`, if the entry for *bar* isn't empty, but this yields an error message.

MWP

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb[keys={foo,bar,foobar}]{mydatabase}{testbase.csv}

\newcommand{\printcommand}[2][]{%
 \begin{longtabu}to\textwidth{@{}llX@{}}
 \firsthline
 Foo&Bar&Foobar\\
 \hline\endhead
 \DTLforeach*{#2}{\foo=foo,\bar=bar,\foobar=foobar}{%
%   \ifdefempty{\bar}{}{\hline}%
  \foo&\bar&\foobar\\
  }
 \end{longtabu}
}

\begin{document}
foobar

\printcommand{mydatabase}
\end{document}
```

The `testbase.csv` looks like this

```
myfoo,mybar,myfoobar
17,barbar,bar 1
,,bar 234
,,barbary
23,ba ba ba,\(a^2+b^2=c^2\)
,,\emph{barfoo}
,,foofoofoo
```

If I compile like this, I get no errors, but if I uncomment the commented line, I get `misplaced \noalin` and `misplaced \omit` errors.

If I replace `longtabu` by `tabu` (and remove the then undefined `\endhead`), I get even more errors.

How can I make this work the way I want?

Comment: Have you tried changing the order (hline after linebreak)?

Comment: There is no `\linebreak` in the code. Only `\\` and this ends previous lines of the table.

Comment: Yeah, and in a table hline as to be after \\.

Comment: So I asked, how to determine, if the previous line has ended over here ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378349/in-a-tabular-how-to-make-sure-previous-line-has-ended/ ) and got the command `\crcr` as a result, that behaves like `\cr` except if there was `\cr` before, in which case, it does nothing. But this doesn't work here, as expected: If added before the `\hline` in the commented line, it adds an empty line. So the `\ifdefempty` seems to add something, so that `\hline` breaks, because it's not directly after newline and `\crcr` is like `\cr`, because it's not directly after `\cr`.

Comment: @Toscho: Is this the output you're after - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALshK.png)? A horizontal line `\hline` to separate every `\bar` case - [code](https://pastebin.com/T6kHWNYD). Note the use of `\DTLiffirstrow`.

Comment: Yes, that's the output, I'm looking for.

Comment: @Werner `\DTLiffirstrow` only checks the first input line, but I would have to check for the first outputline of each page.

Comment: @Toscho: Perhaps it will help if you write up a complete example that shows the expected output for a (say) 2-page table. There seems to be cases where the suggestions work, and other cases where it doesn't. Please spoon-feed us that kind of information.

Comment: Really recommend not using `tabu` or `longtabu` unless you want buggy code which will break completely at some unspecified future date.

Comment: @cfr Do you have sound arguments for this statement of yours or is this just whining about `tabu`?

Comment: @Toscho Yes. This is based on dialogue between egreg and `tabu`'s author. The author has promised backwards-incompatible changes and refuses to fix bugs in the meantime, even when provided with all the information required to do so. (That is, I'm not talking about refusing to spend hours trying to track down a bug in code you're about to replace anyway.) If you think that's 'just whining', fine. But don't look for any sympathy when you have to rewrite every `tabu` in your book or dissertation after inadvertently breaking it by updating your TeX installation.

Comment: @Toscho https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121841/is-the-tabu-package-obsolete/121847#121847 Perhaps you think that is 'just whining about `tabu`', too? Gosh! How unfair!

Answer (score 1):

Your error is pretty simple. You try to place a `\hline` without having the previous line ended. That won't work (with or without loop). Try

```
\DTLforeach*{#2}{\foo=foo,\bar=bar,\foobar=foobar}{%
  \foo&\bar&\foobar\\
  \ifdefempty{\bar}{}{\hline}%
}
```

and you'll see that it compiles to

[image: longtabu]

Probably you'll say that this is not what you want. I know, but your check does not work for outputting a hline before. You would have to ensure that the previous line ends with something like `\\`.

Comment: But with my code, I'm sure, that there is a `\\ ` before that line: The head ends with such a `\\ `, and every line in the loop ends with such a `\\ `.