# In a tabular, how to make sure, previous line has ended?

Tags: tables, line-breaking

If one is in a `tabular` environment, how can one make sure, that the previous line has ended (with `\\`)?

One might want to add an `\hline` or do some other stuff only at the beginning of a new line.

If one adds `\\` before, that might add an unwanted, additional empty line.

So the question is, in comparison to `\clearpage` vs. `\newpage`, if there is a likewise command for `tabular` `\???` vs. `\\`?

Comment: This question looks like an “X-Y” problem (ask about Y when you are actually trying to achieve X), so I’m not going to answer it; but as a hint, recall that *immediately* after a `\\ ` TeX is in vertical mode, and this condition can be tested with `\ifvmode`.

Answer (score 4):

The following introduces a `t`abular `n`ew`l`ine macro `\tnl` which checks whether it's followed by `\tnl` using `\@ifnextchar`. Since `\@ifnextchar` leaves the "peeked token" in the input stream, concatenated called to `\tnl` are all ignored, except for the last one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tnl}{\@ifnextchar\tnl{}{\\}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l }
  one \\ two
\end{tabular}\quad
\begin{tabular}{ l }
  one \tnl two
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}[t]{ l }
  one \\ \\ two
\end{tabular}\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{ l }
  one \tnl \tnl two
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}[t]{ l }
  one \\ \\ \\ two
\end{tabular}\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{ l }
  one \tnl \tnl \tnl two
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This does remove the optional argument specification that accompanies `\\`. Not sure whether that's needed.

Comment: This command `\tnl` seems to do the same a `\crcr` in David Carlisle's answer (as far as I can see). And it yields the same result in my other question ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378324/how-to-make-ifdefempty-on-datatool-entries-work-in-longtabu/ ).

Answer (score 3):

Mostly you can use the TeX primitive `\crcr` to achieve this. `\crcr` acts like `\cr` unless the previous command was `\cr` in which case it does nothing.

This is the heart of the reason that latex can ignore a `\\` at the end of the final row.

the only wrinkle is that if you end the previous row with `\crcr` then it as if it was ended with `\cr` rather than `\\` but in most cases this comes to the same thing.

Comment: Thx for the hint on `\crcr`, but this does not work as I expect it in my other question ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378324/how-to-make-ifdefempty-on-datatool-entries-work-in-longtabu/ ). If I add `\crcr` before the `\hline` in the commented line, the code compiles without erros, but adds an empty line.

Comment: @Toscho well that's not surprising:-) `\crcr` only does nothing if there are no non-expandable commands since the last `\cr` the chance that that's the case in the middle of that loop is small. You would be better to put  either `\\ ` or `\\\hline` at the beginning of each row, at the point you can test `\bar`

Answer (score 3):

Just to illustrate the suggestion I made in [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378349/in-a-tabular-how-to-make-sure-previous-line-has-ended#comment937682_378349):

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\newcommand*{\ensureLineHasEnded}{\ifvmode \else \expandafter \\\fi}
\newcommand*{\NLhline}{\ensureLineHasEnded\hline}



\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    A one-column \texttt{tabular}, just for demo purposes.  \\
    \NLhline
    It uses both vertical and horizontal rules (arrggh\ldots!).  \\
    \NLhline
    But some of the \verb|\\|~commands are missing\ldots
    \NLhline
    \ldots yet the horizontal rules are typeset normally.  \\*[6pt]
    \NLhline
    The \verb|\ensureLineHasEnded| can take the same optional arguments\ldots
    \ensureLineHasEnded*[6pt]\hline
    \ldots as the \verb|\\|~command.
    \NLhline
    Moreover, it works as expected when used at the end of the \texttt{tabular}.
    \ensureLineHasEnded[9pt]
\end{tabular}\par

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:** As David Carlisle [has remarked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378349/in-a-tabular-how-to-make-sure-previous-line-has-ended/378361?noredirect=1#comment937699_378361), the `\ifvmode` test does not work if `p`-type columns are used, because TeX is in vertical mode in these columns too.  Note that, more precisely, TeX is *internal* vertical mode both inside `p`-type columns and between the lines of an alignment (*The TeXbook*, p. 282), so a supplementary `\ifinner` test wouldn’t help either.  A distinction that does work *in simple situations* is based on the current group level, which can be enquired about by means of the e-TeX primitive `\currentgrouplevel`.

The following code is just a proof of concept: there’s little point in refining it unless you know the precise context into which it’s going to be used.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\makeatletter

\@ifdefinable\@tabular@group@level{\newcount\@tabular@group@level}
\newcommand*\ensureLineHasEnded{%
    \ifnum \currentgrouplevel>\@tabular@group@level
        % % Diagnostics:
        % \count@ \currentgrouplevel
        % \typeout{Inserting \protect\\ at line \number\inputlineno,
        %     since \number\count@\space > \number\@tabular@group@level}%
        \expandafter \\%
    \fi
}
\newcommand*\saltAwayLevel{%
    \noalign{%
        \global \@tabular@group@level
            \numexpr \currentgrouplevel -\@ne \relax
        % % Diagnostics:
        % \typeout{\number\@tabular@group@level}
    }%
}

\makeatother

\newcommand*{\NLhline}{\ensureLineHasEnded\hline}



\begin{document}

With \texttt{l}~columns:
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|}
        \saltAwayLevel
        \hline
        A one-column \texttt{tabular}, just for demo purposes.  \\%
        \NLhline
        It uses both vertical and horizontal rules (arrggh\ldots!).  \\
        \NLhline
        But some of the \verb|\\|~commands are missing\ldots
        % \typeout{\number\currentgrouplevel}%
        \NLhline
        \ldots yet the horizontal rules are typeset normally.  \\*[6pt]
        \NLhline
        The \verb|\ensureLineHasEnded| can take the same optional arguments\ldots
        \ensureLineHasEnded*[6pt]\hline
        \ldots as the \verb|\\|~command.  \\
        \NLhline
        Moreover, it works as expected when used at the end of the \texttt{tabular}.
        \ensureLineHasEnded[9pt]
    \end{tabular}\par
\end{center}

\bigbreak

With \texttt{p}~columns:
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{.9\linewidth}|}
        \saltAwayLevel
        \hline
        A one-column \texttt{tabular}, just for demo purposes.  \\%
        \NLhline
        It uses both vertical and horizontal rules (arrggh\ldots!).  \\
        \NLhline
        But some of the \verb|\\|~commands are missing\ldots
        % \typeout{\number\currentgrouplevel}%
        \NLhline
        \ldots yet the horizontal rules are typeset normally.  \\*[6pt]
        \NLhline
        The \verb|\ensureLineHasEnded| can take the same optional arguments\ldots
        \ensureLineHasEnded*[6pt]\hline
        \ldots as the \verb|\\|~command.  \\
        \NLhline
        Moreover, it works as expected when used at the end of the \texttt{tabular}.
        \ensureLineHasEnded[9pt]
    \end{tabular}\par
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You can uncomment the diagnostic commands to get additional information on what is going on.

Comment: yes I wondered about suggesting that but that only works if the otherwise bad `\hline` is in an `l` column, if it would be in a `p` column the vmode test would (or at least could) show as true anyway

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it still doesn't work, if I use it in a `\DTLforeach` from `datatool`-package, that produces one line ending with `\\` per iteration. It seems, that `\DTLforeach` does something, which breaks all these checks, before going through the iterated code, although it doesn't print something.

Comment: @Toscho: Indeed, as D.C. [has remarked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378349/in-a-tabular-how-to-make-sure-previous-line-has-ended/378361?noredirect=1#comment937699_378361) the test is not robust enough.  I intend to remove this answer after the usual grace period of 48 hours that I apply, by policy, to all my pieces of nonsense. :-)

Comment: @GuM: would you consider leaving the answer up?  As you say, it’s a slightly flawed answer, but (a) it still works for some use-cases, so may be useful to some readers; (b) other answerers may be able to build on the idea and improve it to something more robust; and (c) having it here together with the explanation of its limitations is useful to anyone else who thinks of using this approach.