# latex tabular package/environment

Tags: tabularx, tabu, tabulary

I always thought, getting to know `tabu` would be my goal (thought since it is some kind of recommended here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables), but now I learnt, it is not actively developed any more (see [Is the tabu package obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121841/is-the-tabu-package-obsolete)) (of course not further improved packages and programs can be good too, but `tabu`, in my opinion, has a lot of bugs and now they won't be fixed).

Therefore, I'm currently searching for a package to do my tabluars, but somehow I cannot really find what I'm looking for. I need:

- tables spanning multiple pages
- make the table spanning the whole pagewidth (like the `X` columntype of `tabu`)
- something to specify the width of the columns
- line breaks if the content of one cell won't fit into the cell (because of the cell width)
- being able to specify that after each row a line will be printed (something like `\everyrow`)

Any suggestions?

Comment: `xltabular` fulfills at least the first 4 criteria.

Comment: Using longtable will also work. You have to use `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` in the preamble and some columns with calculated width so the tabular stretches nicely between the margins. Writing a `\everyrow` command, is left to you as an exercise.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables has been updated recently to remove any recommendation to use tabu

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh, didn't see that, since there is still this part included `much more powerful and flexible tabu environment.` ;)

Comment: @leandriis oh, thanks, I think I'll dig into that one (and in combination with tabularx there should be many things one can change by oneself.

Comment: @Sveinung I'll try (for the tabularx package), but I'm not that experienced, with writing own commands, if I don't get it, I'll come back and ask ;)

Comment: @atticus deleted, thanks.

Comment: Glad someone writes these things, they're very helpful most of the time ;) :+1:

Comment: @Sveinung well my idea would be to refedine `\\` (or `\arraybackslash` of xtabular) to add a `\hline` after every row. Do you have a better thought? ;)