# Custom glossary style, \makenoidxglossaries and \glsgroupskip

Tags: glossaries

The code below creates a glossary table containing acronyms, their representation in math expressions and their description. A custom glossary style `my` is created using `\newglossarystyle`. It is a table with a `\tabularnewline` between every entry group, as set by redefining `\glsgroupskip`. However, the code produces a new line between every entry, not just the groups. By default, groups are based on the first letter of an entry, e.g. ‘bar’ and ‘baz’ should be in a group and ‘foo’ and ‘qux’ are separately grouped.

The default style (i.e. disable the line `\setglossarystyle{my}`) does create groups with extra separation between them. Why/where does my style fail?

Note that I use ‘Option 1’ as defined in the `glossaries` package manual, i.e. `\makenoidxglossaries`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries

\glsaddkey{math}{}{\acem}{\Acem}{\acm}{\Acm}{\ACm}

\newacronym[math=\mathfrak{foo}]{foo}{foo}{Foo}
\newacronym[math=\mathfrak{bar}]{bar}{bar}{Bar}
\newacronym[math=\mathfrak{baz}]{baz}{baz}{Baz}
\newacronym[math=\mathfrak{qux}]{qux}{qux}{Qux}

\newglossarystyle{my}{%
    % redefine theglossary environment
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    % begin
    {\begin{longtabu} spread 0pt {@{}X[1Lm]X[1Lm]X[3Jm]@{}}}%
    % end
    {\bottomrule
    \end{longtabu}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
        \toprule%
        Abbreviation & Symbol in Mathematical Expressions & Description \\ \midrule%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{%
        \tabularnewline%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}%
        &%
        $\acem{##1}$%
        &%
        \glossentrydesc{##1}%
        \\%
    }%
}

\setglossarystyle{my}

\begin{document}
\glsaddallunused
\printnoidxglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not exactly on topic, but I wouldn't use `tabu`.

Comment: @cfr - Please elaborate on that statement. I use it because I like it better than `tabularx` and `tabulary`. What does it do that has adverse effects?

Comment: The author has promised to release an update which will not be backwards compatible. This means that your stuff is likely to break badly at some point, possibly at just the wrong moment. I'll see if I can find the link in a minute. The author also won't fix serious bugs in the current version.

Comment: See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45479/longtable-in-footnote-leads-to-overfull-page/106427#106427) and [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/xRGJTC74uCI). [Here's one bug](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87144/incompatibility-between-verbatim-and-tabu-danger-of-using-scantokens-in-a-pac) in the version *you* have which the author doesn't care about because *his/her* version works OK. Of course, when you finally get the author's version, all your current code will break, and `tabu` as you know it will no longer be available.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll be cautious with the package in the future. The most recent post by the author in the Google+ thread mentions that this summer is aimed at for the release of the reworked package. Even though there will be no backwards compatibility, I believe the functionality will be the same (and enhanced). I do not have too many active documents with tables, therefore it won't be a problem to rewrite a few tabus when that time comes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that grouping does not work properly with tabular styles with glossary-creation 'Option 1'. If you use `\makeglossaries` with the `makeglossaries` script, it works fine. Or, if you use a list style, it works fine. I am not sure if this is a bug or a recognised limitation.

Here is an example with the `makeglossaries` script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\glsaddkey{math}{}{\acem}{\Acem}{\acm}{\Acm}{\ACm}

\newacronym[math=\mathfrak{foo}]{foo}{foo}{Foo}
\newacronym[math=\mathfrak{bar}]{bar}{bar}{Bar}
\newacronym[math=\mathfrak{baz}]{baz}{baz}{Baz}
\newacronym[math=\mathfrak{qux}]{qux}{qux}{Qux}

\newglossarystyle{my}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long3colheader}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
    \toprule
    Abbreviation & Symbol in Mathematical Expressions & Description \tabularnewline\midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{%
     & &\tabularnewline}%
  \setlength\glsdescwidth{.275\textwidth}%
  \setlength\glspagelistwidth{.45\textwidth}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & $\acem{##1}$ & \glossentrydesc{##1}\tabularnewline
  }%
}

\setglossarystyle{my}

\begin{document}
  \glsaddallunused
  \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: grouped entries in tabular]

This was compiled with

```
pdflatex <filename>
makeglossaries <filename>
pdflatex <filename>
```

The problem with using `\makenoidxglossaries` etc. is not that the group skip is ignored. It is that `glossaries` erroneously believes that every entry starts a new group.

Here's an example using a standard style which demonstrates that it is not your particular definition of `my` which causes the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries

\glsaddkey{math}{}{\acem}{\Acem}{\acm}{\Acm}{\ACm}

\newacronym[math=\mathfrak{foo}]{foo}{foo}{Foo}
\newacronym[math=\mathfrak{bar}]{bar}{bar}{Bar}
\newacronym[math=\mathfrak{baz}]{baz}{baz}{Baz}
\newacronym[math=\mathfrak{qux}]{qux}{qux}{Qux}

\setglossarystyle{long3colheader}
\renewcommand*\glsgroupskip{%
  X & X & X\tabularnewline}

\begin{document}
  \glsaddallunused
  \printnoidxglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: too many glossary groups]

If `\makeglossaries` and `\printglossaries` are used instead, the grouping is correct:

[image: correct grouping]

Alternatively, if `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossaries` are used with the default (list) style and

```
\renewcommand*\glsgroupskip{%
  \item XXX}
```

then the grouping is also correct:

[image: correct grouping with list]

Comment: Unless someone else proves you're wrong (on the undocumented limitation of `\makenoidxglossaries`), I believe this would be the best answer to this question. I just wonder why it can recognise groups in a list, which proves it can do its job.

Comment: @Erik They may well prove me wrong. This is just the result of uninformed experimentation;). But I thought it useful as a starting point, at least. In particular, the fact that you get the wrong result with a standard style shows that staring at your particular definition of `my` is unlikely to get at the issue....