# Is option 1 (\makenoidxglossaries) of the glossaries package broken

Tags: glossaries

As recently seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236670/custom-glossary-style-makenoidxglossaries-and-glsgroupskip) there seem to be trouble when going with the internal sorting solution (no makeindex or xindy). When compiling the MWE  the error is:

> Undefined control sequence. \makenoidxglossaries

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,nogroupskip,toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\makenoidxglossaries

\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Index}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}

    \newglossaryentry{potato}{name={potato},plural={potatoes}, description={starchy tuber}}
    \newglossaryentry{cabbage}{name={cabbage},description={vegetable with thick green or purple leaves}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Sample}
\glsaddall

\printnoidxglossary[style=mcolindex]

\end{document}
```

It might be a problem of the installed version:
sudo apt-get install texlive (ubuntu 14.04, 2013.20140215-1) says all packages up to date, I searched for glossaries with `kpsewhich glossaries.sty` and it is installed with several other files which i put [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_MzoTKF7WAicjN3TWNUQVMwamM&usp=sharing). So I seem to have an uptodate version, taken from line within glossaries.sty file:

```
   \ProvidesPackage{glossaries}[2014/01/20 v4.03 (NLCT)]
```

How to proceed?

Comment: "recently" was a year ago, and describes quite a different problem. If `\makenoidxglossaries` is not defined then your glossaries package is probably to old.

Comment: good hint, I will reinstall the texlive version, as it comes from the unix backround (ubuntu) im working from, as well as xindy preinstalled in contrast to miktex  [link](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103wright.pdf)

Comment: My glossaries version is from 2016: `\ProvidesPackage{glossaries}[2016/01/24 v4.21 (NLCT)]`. The CHANGES file says that `\makenoidxglossaries` was added in version v4.04.

Comment: I've noticed that the Linux software mangers often seem to lag behind the latest texlive version. I have fedora but always install using the texlive installer rather than the software manger. I install from the DVD as my broadband isn't good, but you can [download TL from TUG](http://tug.org/texlive/). You can then update using `tlmgr`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was due to outdated software and was resolved by updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment of Ulrike Fischer solved the problem, the glossaries package was not up to date. now its fine with `\ProvidesPackage{glossaries}[2016/01/24 v4.21 (NLCT)]` there. I removed the old version of texlive ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu)) and updated  the whole distro of texlive from the [source](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html)  Nicola suggested. I took it from there using *zip archive install-tl.zip (16mb)* 
 There are so much different explanations and blog posts so starting users get easily confused, thats why using the authors instructions is probably the best way to go.
All it took was to run the perl script inside the zip file, matching the [environment variables for ubuntu](http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-310003.4.1) (as I did not tick of the    [ ] create symlinks to standard directories during the perl script run) and texstudio got me working.